# JavaScript insert text after first parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

everyone. I've got a string looks like

```
var s = "2qf/tqg4/ad(d=d,s(f)d)"
```

And I've got another string

```
var n = "abc = /fd/dsf/sdf/a.doc, "
```

What I want to do is insert n after the first '('

So it will look like

```
"2qf/tqg4/ad(abc = /fd/dsf/sdf/a.doc, d=d,s(f)d)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [`replace`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function:

```
var result = s.replace("(", "("+n);
```

Comment: Would this only changes the first one?

Comment: Yes, you can try it yourself.

Comment: you forgot the first `(` in the replacement string

Answer (score 1):

<strike>This barely needs REs.</strike>

```
var t = s.replace(/\(/, '('+n);
```

This doesn't need REs at all, as [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) takes strings as well as REs to specify what should be replaced.

```
var t = s.replace('(', '('+n);
```